# SQL calculations from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

How i can perform calculations between different tables.
I have a table called `pet` and a table called `breed`.

This is the data in `pet` table:

```
PetID   PetName Gender   Weight  VetBill    BreedID

1       Ralph   Male     24      £324.00 2  2       
2       felix   Male     90      £900.00 2  3       
3       alf     Male     3       £300.00 4  3
```

Data in `breed` table:

```
BreedID BreedName        FoodcostPerKg  HousingCost

1       PitBull          £30.00         £250.00 
2       German Shepherd  £75.00         £400.00 
3       Husky            £25.00         £100.00
```

I need to perform the calculatiion

```
(pet weight * foodcost) + vetBills + Housing cost
```

How can this be calculated for all the pets?

Comment: This question is currently tagged as both 'ms-access' (Microsoft Access) and 'sql-server' (Microsoft SQL Server). Those are two completely different products, although they are sometimes used together. Are both of those tags really appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `INNER JOIN` the two tables using `BreedID`, then you can easily use the data from both tables for the calculation.

```
SELECT p.PetID, 
       p.Name, 
       (p.Weight * b.FoodCostPerKg) + p.VetBill + b.HousingCost AS TotalCost
FROM pet p
INNER JOIN breed b ON p.BreedID = b.BreedID
```

Comment: thanks for that.. will this statement calculate the cost for all the pets? or will i need to initiate the breedID in the statement?
thanks

Comment: This will calculate it for all pets. It takes every record in the pet table and joins it to the relevant breed record. Don't forget to accept an answer once you're satisfied.

Comment: i get this error when i run the statement:"No value given for one or more required parameters."

Comment: Are you using sql-server? What is giving you this error, are you exectuting the query directly against a database or within code? Make sure all the column names in the query exactly match the field names in your tables.

Comment: ran into a problem if i run this as a query in sql database i get some results however if i run this query as part of a code it just repeats the petID?

Comment: Won't be able to do anything about that without seeing your code, and its unlikely that I even know the language. Recommend posting a new question for that sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use SQL Sever and look for SQL query:

you are looking for [`JOIN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which can join records from different tables (here probably by `BreedID` column).

Comment: ok thanks but what will the statement be? because i want it done for all pets not just a single pet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ((PET.Weight*BREED .FoodcostPerKg) + PET.VetBill + BREED.HousingCost) AS CALC_VALUE 
FROM pet as PET, breed as BREED 
where PET.BreedID = BREAD.BreedID
```

Modify this select as suitable in your side since this is offline sample.